# How to add keyframes to a rig?

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes

I have modeled and rigged this dragon with riggify. All seems to be working fine with the rig parented to the dragon with automatic weights and when I try it in pose mode the mesh reacts according to it.

However, I found it first very difficult to insert the first keyframe only succeeding when I pressed the buttons to the right of the object properties menu. However when I then posed the dragon and keyframe the next action noting is happening when I playback, except for the location movement of the dragon.

I really find it hard to insert the first keyframe but what I would like to know is what I am doing wrong in respect of the animation. [image]

[image]

Comment: for the moment, you're keyframing the object, not the armature, if you want to keyframe the armature you need to select the armature, switch to Pose mode, move the bones, and press "i" to save the pose

Comment: Check the second pic.  I did as you said.  By pressing is I could not insert the first keyframe. I only did it by pressing the right buttons in the object properties menu.  Still, after I moved the rig and set the frame to 20 for a test it did not move and the green location and rotation tabs stayed to 0.

Comment: I just keyframed the bone properties and the animation worked.

Comment: if you go in the Properties > Object > Transform panel, you are keyframing the whole armature, not a bone, to keyframe a bone, move your bone in the 3D view, stay in the 3D view and press "i". Also, don't forget to remove all the animations you've created for the whole armature and object.

Comment: I did it.  The main error was that I was not pressing   I   in the 3d view.  I also selected keyframe whole character and all the bones I moved animated.  THANKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go in the *Properties* panel > *Object > Transform* panel, whether you've selected the object or the whole armature in *Object* mode, you'll keyframe the object or the whole armature, not the bones.

If you want to keyframe the bones you need to select the armature, switch to *Pose* mode, move the bones, let your cursor in the *3D View*, and press <kbd>i</kbd> to save.

Don't forget to remove all the animations you've created for the whole armature and object.